# How to add a column with missing values in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
   name    x1     x2
0  a       5      5
1  b       8      6
2  e       3      8
```

I also have a list of `names`as follows.

```
lst = [a, e]
```

I want to add a column named as `final_values` to my current dataframe where;

- if the `name` is in `lst` the column value should be `1`
- else `0`

So, my updated dataframe should look as follows.

```
   name    x1     x2    final_values
0  a       5      5        1
1  b       8      6        0
2  e       3      8        1
```

Is there any easy way of doing this in pandas?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: `df.name.isin(lst).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and cast boolean to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` map:

```
df['final_values'] = df['name'].isin(lst).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['final_values'] = np.where(df['name'].isin(lst), 1, 0)
```